Help regarding combinatorial exercise with constraints
How many solutions are there to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 5500 $, where $x_1, \ldots, x_8 \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $x_1, \ldots, x_8 \geq 0 $, with $ x_3 \geq 300 , x_4 \geq 191 $, $ 255 \leq x_5 \leq 519 $, $285 \leq x_8 \leq 819 $, $ x_2 + x_4 + x_6 = 500 $, and $ x_5 + x_8 < 7x_4 $.
Please note:

I am not allowed to use computational tools otherwise I would have solved this exercise in C++. For instance, for part b I have been suggested to use inclusion-exclusion along with stars and bars.

Solution:
$y_3$ = $x_3$ - 300 and $y_3$ >=0
$y_4$ = $x_4$ - 191 and $y_4$ >=0
$y_5$ = $x_5$ - 255 and $y_5$ >=0  and $y_5$ <= 264
$y_8$ = $x_8$ - 285 and $y_8$ >=0 and $y_8$ <= 534
For i $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ {1,2,6,7} I set $y_i$ = $x_i$.
Constraints to be satisfied are:

$y_1$+...+$y_8$ = 5500-300-191-255-285 = 4469.
$y_2$ + $y_4$ + $y_6$ = 500 - 191 = 309
$y_5$ + $y_8$ < $7y_4$ + 7*191 -255-285 = 797

We can rewrite 1 by substituting $y_2$, $y_4$ and $y_6$:

$y_1$+$y_3$+$y_5$+$y_7$+$y_8$ = 4469 - 309 = 4160

My approach is to basically calculate the product of solutions for constraints 1 and 2, then calculate the solutions for constraints 3 and remove them from the product.
Now I am going to calculate the solutions for each constraint:
Constraint 2:
$\binom{311}{2}$
Constraint 4:
S - S1 - S2 + S1 $ \cap $ S2
S is the upper bound ignored for $y_5$ and $y_8$
S1 is the subset of S where $y_5$ >= 265
S2 is the subset of S where $y_8$ >= 535
$\binom{4164}{4}$ - $\binom{3899}{4}$ - $\binom{3629}{4}$ + $\binom{3364}{4}$
Constraint 3:
in this case I don't know how to act because the number of valid combinations of $y_5$ and $y_8$ for each fixed $y_4$ is finite, but because $y_4$ can take any non-negative integer value, the total number of valid triplets ($y_4, y_5, y_8$) is infinite.

Your solution is too hard to read.  Please use mathjax.

Why don't you enclose each math expression by $ signs ?

@user2661923 I've updated my post.

Your analysis looks good, as far as you took it.  In summary, you are looking for the number of solutions that satisfy the following constraints:

Constraint 1: $y_1 + y_3 + y_5 + y_7 + y_8 = 4160.$

Constraint 2: $y_2 + y_4 + y_6 = 309.$

Constraint 3: $y_1, \cdots, y_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Constraint 4: $y_5 \leq 264.$

Constraint 5: $y_8 \leq 534.$

Constraint 6: $y_5 + y_8 < 7y_4 + 797.$



This is the point that you need to form an overall attack strategy.  If Constraint 6 was ignored, then you could take advantage of the fact that Constraints 1 and 2 share no variables, and simply take the corresponding product.
So, Constraint 6, at first glance, seems like a tough nut to crack.  However, if you examine Constraints 4, 5, and 6, collectively, everything falls into place.
That is, $~264 + 534 = 798.~$  Further, the minimum value of $~7y_4 + 797~$ is $~797,~$ which is only achieved if $~y_4 = 0.~$
So, the only (otherwise satisfying) ordered triplets $~(y_5, y_8, y_4)~$ that violate Constraint 6 are:

Violation 1: $~y_5 = 264, y_8 = 533, y_4 = 0.$

Violation 2: $~y_5 = 263, y_8 = 534, y_4 = 0.$

Violation 3: $~y_5 = 264, y_8 = 534, y_4 = 0.$


So, the strategy is clear.  You temporarily ignore Constraint 6, compute the corresponding product, and then adjust for Constraint 6.

$\underline{\text{Temporarily Ignoring Constraint 6}}$
You end up with
$$\binom{311}{2}$$
$$\times \left[ ~\binom{4164}{4} - \binom{3899}{4} - \binom{3629}{4} + \binom{3364}{4} ~\right].$$

$\underline{\text{Adjusting For Violations 1 Through 3}}$
In this section, you are computing the number of solutions if any of Violations 1 through 3 occur.  This computation will be deducted from the previous computation.
For all three violations, you have $~y_4 = 0.~$
So, since Constraint 2 (in effect) becomes $~y_2 + y_6 = 309,~$ the first violation factor is
$$\binom{310}{1}.$$
For the three violations, you end up with 
$~y_5 + y_8 = 797, ~y_5 + y_8 = 797, ~$ or $~y_5 + y_8 = 798.$
Therefore, you (in effect) have
$y_1 + y_3 + y_7 = 3363, 3363, ~$ or $~3362.$
So, the second violation factor is
$$\binom{3365}{2} + \binom{3365}{2} + \binom{3364}{2}.$$
Therefore, the overall computation of violation solutions is
$$\binom{310}{1}$$
$$\times \left[ ~\binom{3365}{2} + \binom{3365}{2} + \binom{3364}{2} ~\right].$$

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
Set
$$B = $$
$$\binom{311}{2}$$
$$\times \left[ ~\binom{4164}{4} - \binom{3899}{4} - \binom{3629}{4} + \binom{3364}{4} ~\right].$$
Set
$$C = $$
$$\binom{310}{1}$$
$$\times \left[ ~\binom{3365}{2} + \binom{3365}{2} + \binom{3364}{2} ~\right].$$
Then, the final computation is
$$B - C.$$
